# How can I stop receiving e-mail notifications when people join my company's network?

Tags: yammer

Every time someone joins our company's network, I get an e-mail. It says in the e-mail that I get that e-mail because I'm following a conversation, but every person joining is a new conversation. I'm also not following the joined topic and in the notification settings I cannot find any option that concerns these notifications.

My colleages are not receiving these notifications. My company has just decided to promote Yammer use internally which now results in floods of these kinds of e-mails. What do I need to do to turn this off?

UPDATE:
It is a paid network.
I am not an admin.
We don't have active directory
I am not inviting them.

Comment: Did the answer help you Mathijs?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, no, I already looked around in the notification area: "in the notification settings I cannot find any option that concerns these notifications.". I have updated my answer with the questions. However, I realise I should add a comment to his answer stating that I did for Peter to get notified.

Comment: PS: I've solved my problem by just deselecting all notifications and only asking for a weekly digest.

Answer (score 1):

You can always tweak your notification settings for your account by going to a URL similar to:

```
https://www.yammer.com/[YourNetworkName]/account/notifications
```

Can you please also provide a bit of background? Is this a paid network? Are you a verified admin? Do you have active directory sync enabled? Are you inviting these users, or are they just signing up?

Comment: I updated the question with your questions